# Java-Web-Start gives NoClassDefFoundError in my application to create docx files

Tags: java, java-web-start, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception, docx4j

I have an application to create .docx files. It works perfectly fine on my local PC, but gives error on java-web-start:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/docx4j/fonts/Mapper
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.docx4j.fonts.Mapper

Application gives that error when I click my "create docx" button, other features(my gui, db connections..) still work fine. Clicking the button, application opens an existing docx file, adds a table to it and saves the file on my local PC.

Actually 'missing' class is there in docx4j-2.7.0.jar, in the lib folder. Other jar files in the folder also creates no problem. But the docx4j jar file is the largest in size which is 2,67MB. May that be the problem? Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an import in  `org.docx4j.fonts.Mapper` is not satisfied. Look at the dependencies form `docx4j` if are in the classpath.

It might be an error with dependencies in the `jnpl`.

```
<resources> </resources>
```

Regards.

Comment: I got the dependency pack in the classpath.It does look like an import fault, but problem arises with jnlp, in my local PC everything looks fine and code works.

Comment: You are right, as I wrote the jnlp file manually, I have realized that I forgot to put jar files list to jnlp file.Thanks for the reply.